# graphical svn client for creating branches, merging branches etc?

Tags: svn

hi i wonder if there are some GUI softwares to administrate a svn repo?

or do you actually have to log into the ubuntu server with ssh and use all the svn commands to copy the trunk to a branch, merge the data back and forth, copy to a tag, delete and so on...

im using netbeans in mac. i think it's only handling the communication between a local project and the repo. not the flows between trunc, branch and tag (creating, deleting, viewing differences etc)

Comment: @Zoredache, unfortunately the other two questions are still here... the wheels take too long to move on SF sometimes...

Comment: Apparently all the mods are too busy moving one question about unicorns...

Comment: This question and the one before seem like weak April Fool's jokes.  And I guess the mods are still too busy...

Comment: Because I can't believe anyone could know about SVN and not have heard about Tortoise.

Comment: ive got mac and not windows, and im new to svn. "I can't believe..." are you joking? u hear what words you are using? i´ve got a life beside :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do your work on Windows, you can use the TortoiseSVN tool. It integrates into the windows shell - you'll be able to right-click an empty folder and choose to check out a repository. From that checkout, you can use the tool to create branches or tags, and merge changes between branches and trunk.